# How to access remote hadoop system(Sandbox on Azure)

Tags: azure, hadoop, intellij-idea, hdfs, java

Context - Trying to access remote linux machine which has hadoop installed(sandbox) from my local machine using IntelliJ. I tried using below code but Im getting an error. I'm not able to understand the exact problem. Anyone else have faced similar issue?

> Error:Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local
>   exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException:
>   Protocol message tag had invalid wire

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.;

Comment: Do you have ports opened in network security group in Azure for such actions?

Comment: Yes they are open..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could not connect to your Azure Linux machine via IntelliJ. The issue might be caused by missing an inbound rule in the NSG for your VM to allow the inbound traffic to the port required by IntelliJ. Please refer to the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-portal#manage-rules to create an inbound rule. If you don't know which ports & protocols need to be allowed, you can type wildcard character `*` to allow any ports and select `Any` source & `Any` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using Hortonworks sandbox which has a docker. I want to use one of the ports of the docker to access the docker. This has to be done by modifying the docker script to do port forwarding to the host VM and that port must be used to connect to the docker